# How to open a new activity from a dialog fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, android-dialogfragment

My program opens a DialogFragment class while running in MainActivity.java

I want to be able to click on the "neutral button" of that dialog and open a new activity, SensorDataDisplay.java

I am having trouble finding the right way to reference the Context in my button's onClick.

```
package com.august.customtisensortagclient;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GetInfoDialog extends DialogFragment {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {





        final String thisWhichGetInfoDialog = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getWhichGetInfoDialog();
        final ArrayList<String> thisScannedDevicesArrayList =
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getScannedDevicesArrayList();
        final int thisIsInLeftConnectedDeviceDisplay = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getIsInLeftConnectedDeviceDisplay();
        final int thisIsInRightConnectedDeviceDisplay = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getIsInRightConnectedDeviceDisplay();
        int thisIsInThisConnectedDeviceDisplay = 0;

        if (thisWhichGetInfoDialog == "Left") {
            thisIsInThisConnectedDeviceDisplay = thisIsInLeftConnectedDeviceDisplay;
        } else if (thisWhichGetInfoDialog == "Right")
            thisIsInThisConnectedDeviceDisplay = thisIsInRightConnectedDeviceDisplay;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(thisWhichGetInfoDialog + " Sensor Info");
        builder.setMessage("MAC Address: " + thisScannedDevicesArrayList.get(thisIsInThisConnectedDeviceDisplay));
        builder.setNeutralButton("View Data", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(?????, SensorDataDisplay.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("key", "TEST VALUE"); //Optional parameters
                ?????.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getActivity() returns the Activity the fragment is attached to**

```
builder.setNeutralButton("View Data", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SensorDataDisplay.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("key", "TEST VALUE"); //Optional parameters
                    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

`DialogFragment` has `getActivity()` and `getContext()` methods (which it inherits from `Fragment`), both will work in your case. If you're having trouble accessing these methods from the anonymous class (which shouldn't be the case), you can use the `GetInfoDialog.this.getActivity()` syntax.